# Footer Loses column background color while resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a 3 column footer in bootstrap. However when I resize the footer below 990px the second and third column lose the background color I set for the whole footer.

---html---

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 footer1">
                      </div>
             <div class="col-md-5 footer2">
          </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 footer3">
     </div>
  </footer>
```

To prevent overflows I am using:

```
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}`
```

and for the footer I created I am using:

```
footer
{
    background-color: #34495e;
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%
}
```

When I add `overflow:hidden` to the footer the second and third column disappear.

Comment: Can you post yout HTML code?

Comment: Do you want to keep each column resizes when windows resizes? or do you want columns go under each other as default behavior is expected?

Comment: i dont mind if they stack or not but i want the color to fil the container and don't leave white bars...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `@media-queries`?
You might add this to your CSS code under `footer`.

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
  footer {
    height:auto;
  }
}
```

And when window's height is under `990px`, footer's height must be `auto` in order to keep seeing the under stacked columns.

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/mikegohome/g70ugggh/) and resizes the area in order to see changes

By the way, there were 2 `</div>` missing in your HTML

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-4  footer1">

             </div>
             <div class="col-md-5  footer2">

             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3  footer3">

             </div>
         </div> <!---  <---This close tag is missing -->
      </div> <!---  <---This close tag is missing -->
  </footer>
```

Comment: unfortunately that did note work....i have to mention that above that i have another container with fixed boxes and i believe that the problem starts from there. while resizing the boxes get merged together and the footer doesnt get filed with the color...